# MySQL - Which file is running a query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to trace an issue, I need to know which file is running a particular query, is it possible to see what file is executing a command?

I've enabled general_log and I can see the query.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell just from a SQL query which file of code is running it.

You don't state in your question what programming language you're using, or how your application connects to the database, or if you're using a data access layer or ORM library.

But it's true in many programming languages that a database connection is created by one file, but queries are formed in other code files. They might even be formed by a different code file that ultimately sends the query to the MySQL server to be executed.

You need to read through your code and understand how queries are formed and executed.

Some programmers add comments to their SQL queries, which end up in the query log.

```
$sql = "/* File: reports.php; Line: 278 */ SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 = ? ORDER BY blah";
```

This takes some work to set it up initially, but then you can use the query log to find out where any query is run from.

Note that this does not work for queries run by the `mysql` client, because that client removes comments before executing queries.

---

Re your comment:

If you think your database is being hacked, then first you should make sure your network security is sufficient to prevent any external clients from reaching your database. That is, only your own app should be allowed to connect. You can do this with a combination of network firewalls and SQL `GRANT` statements.

It's surprising how many people run databases on a server that is exposed to the internet! If this is you, then you should fix this immediately. Take your website down until you do. It's unsafe.

Once you are sure that only your app has access, and no other client can connect, then you can add code as I described above to your app so that every query identifies itself.

If you use a database access layer, you might only need to do this in one place. If you have SQL queries scattered throughout your app, it's going to take more work, because you'll have to edit every file until you figure out which one is the source of the query.

Comment: Great answer Bill. Unfortunately, I'm trying to track a hack and I'm not sure who / where the file is running from.